# How to draw squares inside a div element in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple html div that will serve as like a viewport. and i need to draw 1 or more squares inside this div

```
<div style= "height: 400px; width: 400px; background-color: powderblue;"> </div>
```

I already can receive the dimension of the squares or rectangles. and upon receiving this data i must be able to draw squares that has no fill.

```
{x: 10, y: 20, height: 50, width: 50}
{x: 210, y: 120, height: 100, width: 70}
```

There can be 1 or more squares, and i must also be able to delete the drawn squares. But before all of that, how do i fist draw a square inside the div element just like the picture below? Squares that goes out of bounds of the div must be clipped

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at this: [Drawing_shapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes)?? Use the `canvas` element, [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [canvas api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/canvas) to draw shapes.

Make sure to set the size of the canvas element with css, and shapes should be clipped according to that size.

To delete a shape, simply delete the data, clear the canvas, and redraw.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

let rects = [
  {x: 10, y: 20, height: 50, width: 50},
  {x: 210, y: 120, height: 100, width: 70},
];

rects.forEach(r => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.rect(r.x, r.y, r.width, r.height);
  ctx.stroke();
});
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" />
```

Comment: Should i change my div into canvas or add a child element? Also is canvas built in to browser? as the application is done offline, i cant download reference scripts

Comment: Either would work, whatever works bets for you.  And canvas works with default javascript.

Comment: I made an entire Tetris game using the canvas api for a class.  It was all offline

Comment: Im making progress, but how do i clear the canvas? so i can draw new squares?

Comment: Here is the documentation to clear an area.  Examples including. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect

Answer (score 1):

You can set `position: relative` on the parent `div` and then use `position: absolute` and `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` for the children.

Something like this:

```
<div style= "height: 400px; width: 400px; background-color: powderblue;">
 <div style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 20px; height: 50px; width: 50px"></div>
</div>
```

You may need to add `overflow: hidden` on the parent and also add some borders on the children so they are visible.

Comment: How do i append(and also delete) those child div in javascript good sir? The default html has no children in them,so it has to be javascript who will be doing the adding and deleting